# Math function incudes 3 variable but one of them seems not counted

Tags: c#

l m trying to do a math game includes many levels. so far, l completed 3-level but on level-2, math function did not work. there are 3 variable and last variable seems not counted while doing math functions.
for example: 5 (Q1) + 7 (Q2)- 2 ( Q3) here result is 10 but on my code, it gives 12, Q3 variable not counted.

on level 3, also l use three variable and l checked level 3 works well. so got code of it and pasted in level 2 and l made some arrangements but still same problem.

here is the code of level-2 and level-3

```
     private void level2()
      {
        int Q21, Q22, Q23,top = 0;
        List<string> opersembols = new List<string> { "/", "+", "-", "*"};
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Random rndOP = new Random();
        int OPIndex = rndOP.Next(1, 3);
        int OPIndex2 = rndOP.Next(1, 3);
        pn1.Hide();
        pn2.Show();

        Q21 = rnd.Next(0, 20);
        Q22 = rnd.Next(0, 20);
        Q23 = rnd.Next(0, 20);

        Q21BTN.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21);
        Q22BTN.Text = Convert.ToString(Q22);
        Q23BTN.Text = Convert.ToString(Q23);

        OPBTN1.Text = opersembols[OPIndex];
        OPBTN2.Text = opersembols[OPIndex2];
        switch (OPBTN1.Text)
        {
            case "+":
                switch (OPBTN2.Text)
                {
                    case "+":
                        top = (Q21 + Q22) + Q23;
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(top);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        top = (Q21 + Q22)-Q23;
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(top);
                        break;

                }

                break;

            case "-":
                switch (OPBTN2.Text)
                {
                    case "+":
                        top = (Q21 - Q22) + Q23;
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(top);
                        break;

                    case "-":
                        top = (Q21 - Q22) - Q23;
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(top);
                        break;


                }

                break;

        }



    }
    private void level3()
    {
        int Q21, Q22, Q23 = 0;
        List<string> opersembols = new List<string> { "/", "+", "-","*" };
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Random rndOP = new Random();
        int OPIndex = rndOP.Next(1, 4);
        int OPIndex2 = rndOP.Next(1, 4);
        pn1.Hide();
        pn2.Show();
        TimeBTN.Text = "0";
        timer1.Start();

        Q21 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        Q22 = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        Q23 = rnd.Next(0, 10);

        Q21BTN.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21);
        Q22BTN.Text = Convert.ToString(Q22);
        Q23BTN.Text = Convert.ToString(Q23);
        timer1.Start();

        OPBTN1.Text = opersembols[OPIndex];
        OPBTN2.Text = opersembols[OPIndex2];
        switch (OPBTN1.Text)
        {
            case "+":
                switch (OPBTN2.Text)
                {
                    case "+":
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21 + Q22 + Q23);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21 + Q22 - Q23);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21 + Q22 * Q23);
                        break;

                }

                break;

            case "-":
                switch (OPBTN2.Text)
                {
                    case "+":
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21 - Q22 + Q23);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21 - Q22 - Q23);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21 - Q22 * Q23);
                        break;

                }

                break;

            case "*":
                switch (OPBTN2.Text)
                {
                    case "+":
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21 * Q22 + Q23);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21 * Q22 - Q23);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        BTNREST2.Text = Convert.ToString(Q21 * Q22 * Q23);
                        break;

                }

                break;

        }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code you want us to debug for you.  When *you* debug the code, which *specific operation* produces an unexpected result?  What were the runtime values of the variables at the time?  What result did you get?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: Note that `Q21 + Q22 * Q23` will do the multiplication before the addition.  Is that what you really want because in your level 2 you have `(Q21 + Q22) + Q23` to ensure the operation on Q21 and Q22 is done first.

Comment: what l want is Q21 +/- Q22 +/- Q23 (on level 2). but What I got is Q21 +/- Q22. On level-3, (Q21 +/- Q22 +/- Q23 ) is working fine. what l wonder why on leve-3 is working but on level 2, it is not working. what am l missing here.

Comment: @ömersarı: What you're missing is called "debugging".  If you're not familiar with the use of a debugger, now is the time to start.  With a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes, observing the exact runtime behaviors and the changing runtime values of your variables.  As you observe the result of each individual line of code in succession, you should encounter a line of code which produces a result you didn't expect.  Which line was it?  What was the result?  What did you expect?  Why?  Now is the time to debug your code.

Comment: Got it and ı solved it after debugging. there was an issue with  "if- function". it was ignore the level 2 calculations and go on with level 1. l made simple mistake. ı m not good at coding. ı m trying to learn so thanks for help.